# How do I change text on a page actively with a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if this question was asked before, I've tried searching but am unsure of how exactly to phrase my search.

I have a textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="text"></input>
```

I also have a paragraph:

```
<p id="para"></p>
```

What I want to achieve is for the text within the paragraph to change **as** the user types stuff in the textbox, done with jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is lazy. Surprised you even got an answer.

Comment: 3 lines of code, at the most. At least make an attempt. Hint: keyup()

Comment: I don't even know how to start out, ie: where to define the variables, on window load or on document ready? And how to cause the textbox to "call" on the javascript, onKeyDown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#text').keyup(function() {
         $('#para').html($('#text').val());
    });
</script>
```

Easy as that, please try to Google before posting questions, e.g., "jquery event keys".

EDIT: `keypress` doesn't return the last character, as some other answer pointed out. Changed to `keyup`. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3kDN/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not know exactly how to phrase the search terms for my question, now I know.

Comment: jQuery is very useful for handling page objects because of it's syntax and documentation, so you've made a good choice! It can be intimidating if you're new, but if you ever have a problem with jQuery, try looking through their site http://api.jquery.com/ and you'll probably find what you want to find without having to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Keypress doesn't work since it gives you the text without the last pressed character.

```
$("#text").keyup(function() {

    $("#para").html($(this).val());

});
```